# count number of columns that not null in a row

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I've been working with laravel for just over 8 months, and I have a problem where i want to show the completed percent in a table. so the idea I had was that I was going to count the number of columns that are not null in a row and then divide by a number of columns in a row and multiply by 100.

Something like `(NumberOfNotNullColumns/totalNumberOfColumns)*100`

But the problem is I can't get NumberOfNotNullColumns in a selected row.

```
    $pos_info =  DB::select(DB::raw('SHOW COLUMNS FROM resource'));
        $pos_info_act =  DB::select(DB::raw('SELECT count(*) from resource WHERE * IS NOT NULL AND user_id = '.$resource->user_id));
foreach ($pos_info as $item) $base_columns += 1;
        $percentage = ($pos_info_act/$pos_info)*100;
```

as you can see am not experienced with MySQL

Comment: Can you please show us the table attributes?

Comment: You can do select all all required columns, filter out columns with null and calculate.Have you tried any code?

Comment: Please could you provide some code that you have written to attempt this functionality.

Comment: @LucasPiazzi i want to do same thing to multiple tables so i want it to be dynamic

Comment: `(User::whereNotNull('column')->count() / User::count()) * 100` or whatever your model is...

Comment: $pos_info =  DB::select(DB::raw('SHOW COLUMNS FROM resource'));
        $pos_info_act =  DB::select(DB::raw('SELECT count(*) from resource WHERE * IS NOT NULL AND user_id = '.$resource->user_id));
        $percentage = ($pos_info_act/$pos_info)*100;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone is interested this is how i ended up doing it

```
private function complete_percentage($model, $table_name, $resource){
    $pos_info =  DB::select(DB::raw('SHOW COLUMNS FROM '.$table_name));
    $base_columns = count($pos_info);
    $not_null = 0;
    foreach ($pos_info as $col){
        $not_null += app('App\\'.$model)::selectRaw('SUM(CASE WHEN '.$col->Field.' IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS not_null')->where('user_id', '=', $resource->user_id)->first()->not_null;
    }

    return ($not_null/$base_columns)*100;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the below query,

```
select (sum(case when column is not null then 1 else 0 end)/sum(case when column is null then 1 else 0 end))*100 from tableName
```

Answer (score 0):

Using model query

```
$all = Resource::count();
$notNull = Resource::whereNotNull('your_field_name')->count();
$percent = ($notNull/$all)*100;
print_r($percent);
exit;
```

Using DB query

```
$all = DB::table('resource')->count();
$notNull = DB::table('resource')->whereNotNull('your_field_name')->count();
$percent = ($notNull/$all)*100;
print_r($percent);
exit;
```

**You need to specify any one column which is null or not null**

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is interested PD: sorry I speak Spanish, use a translator into English.

Testing in Lavarel 6

```
  //consulting specific user

   $user = User::find(Auth::id());
   //counters
   $contadornull = 0;
   $cantidadcampos = 0;

   // using $user->getFillable() for return all fields the model

    foreach ($user->getFillable() as $key => $campos) {

        //exclude data were user not filliables

        if($campos != 'fotografia' && $campos != 'rango' && $campos != 'password' && 
         $campos != 'estatus')
        {
            //count all fields
            $cantidadcampos = $cantidadcampos + 1;
            //count fields where value is null

            if($user->$campos != null)
            {
                $contadornull++;
            }
        }
        

        
    }
   //calculate percentage
    $porcentaje = $contadornull / $cantidadcampos * 100;
```

Comment: While your answer may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please edit your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/28199218)

Comment: the explanation is in the comments of the code. is valid..?